# Customize Android Menu Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, menuitem

i am using the Support Library Navigation Drawer and I want to customize it.

My Current Menu looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

<group
    android:id="@+id/DrawerMainGroup"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/home"
        />...
```

I want to have another icon on this. Do you think it is possible?
I searched the Web and could not fin anything useful for me.

Both images will be dynamically loaded. For example:

I have a app where i can get videos,pictures etc. That is the first Icon. Next to this, there should be a icon if this site is on homescreen or not.

Like: (IconType)(IconOnHome) Text

I don't know if this is even possible. I found app:actionlayout already, but i am not sure if I could load different images in to the xml.

Comment: That is not supported by menu resources, and so it is unlikely to be supported by `NavigationView`. Note that you do not have to use `NavigationView` to have a nav drawer; you are welcome to put your own `ListView` or `RecyclerView` in there, with rows formatted however you want.

Comment: Thanks for this fast reply. Then I have to think about another solution for my problem.